# How to create this text glitch effect(End credits sequence of WandaVision)

Tags: text-object

How to create this text glitch effect from the End credits sequence of WandaVision? I understand there is more effects here like chromatic aberration and motion blur... How can I achieve this specific glitch effect?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwkCZV4exSY&ab_channel=RESHADEDCLIPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the RGB layers in the *Compositor* with a *Converter > Separate RGBA* node, use a node to warp each layer, like for example *Distort > Lens Distortion*, then recombine the RGB in a *Converter > Combine RGBA*:

[image]

There may be a better node but I don't know which one could warp like it does in your video, maybe also try a blur filter, or a *Distort > Transform*, etc.

If you want to do it directly in the scene, you can warp an image texture with the Musgrave node for example, and overlay several image textures of different colors (below just one layer), it's probably a bit tedious but closer to what we see in your video:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to try and find a solution for my question. I did try your suggested way for the chromatic aberration part of the effect, and I love how it looks, especially with the 'Dispersion' effect of the 'Lens Distortion' node. However, I feel I have more to learn and research about the effect. I know I can export a sequence of some text animation and try to manipulate the coordinates of it even with the object material nodes (as image texture input)...

Comment: ...using the help of some other texture in order to manipulate the coordinates of the input image texture , but here is the problem, what texture and what settings to use to achieve this specific glitch effect?

Comment: sure, maybe post your own answer

Comment: I don't know if I will be able to achieve this though... They probably used AF for the glitch effect, but they did the glitch effect in such an elegant way...  Anyway, I will sure update if I will somehow get to a similar result with Blender. Thank you again for your contribution to my question!

Comment: Yes you can use the material to create this effect, I'm looking into how to do, a bit more complicated than with the Compositor though

Comment: Yes, thank you, It will take some time for me to research though, but I've seen great effects that can be done with the object material nodes like old VHS effect for example to a image/video input texture , so who knows? Maybe the answer to this question is hiding there:)

Comment: old VHS is another question, but it can be done in the Compositor with the same Separate RGBA nodes, and effects like blur etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136080/discussion-between-blender28-and-moonboots).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed effort regarding creating this effect. I do believe it is a very good way to recreate this text animation effect in Blender. There were some issues for me to recreate the same dispersion/chromatic aberration part of the effect as in the original video, and I don't know if I can get the same very effect in Blender as in the video, but overall, your way is a very cool way to create this effect!  oh and please accept my apology for this late answer, as I had very little free time this week for all things Blender:)